# Activating account after registering to a web application

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

Basically, I am developing a web application based on the Spring Framework where I would like users to confirm their initial registration with an email, which gets sent out to them once they register with the application. They cannot login until they confirm that email.
Could someone help with a tutorial or something? I am new to implementing this sought of feature.

Thanks

Comment: Send a link with unique parameter to user eamil address.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Any tutorials which show you the implementation?

Comment: Implementation is easy, you can write yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not an all in one approach,
but with a mix of tutorials I think you can create one.

**Approach**

- create a signup form and a controller class which creates a user object and display a signup completed page

  http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/
- in the signup controller class send out an activation email

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-sending-e-mail-via-gmail-smtp-server-with-mailsender/

- Create a second method in the signup controller which accepts the activation code as a RequestParameter and activates the user
- Add a custom user details spring security implementation, which loads the user from the database and checks if the user is activated. In the `loadUserByUsername` method you return a [user](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) object, which also contains a enabled property which represents if the user is activated or not.

http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/16/custom-userdetailsservice-example-for-spring-3-security/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a built in functionality in Spring Security for this. What I would do:

- set up Spring Security with your application and database, there are a lot of tutorials on the web. Here you can configure the queries that retrieves the users for authentication, in these queries I would include an activated flag, so the users cannot log in until they activate it
- write an own logic which sends email with an unique id, then another one which sets the aforementioned flag when the user clicked on the link.

Yes, it doesn't sound simple.

Comment: How could you send email for registered users.

Comment: With an SMTP server, and of course users have to register their email address.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it?